# Changing the function of a button in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So below I have some code of what I'm working with. Right now, if you just launch the website, the `#picture` div has a background image, and if you press any of the buttons, that picture is replaced with something else.

So what I can't figure out is how the buttons would change what they do after pressing a button. Let's say you click on Button 1 and the background image is replaced. I want the buttons to recognize what background image is in that div and change functions accordingly, in my case, I want them to change what pictures they replace the current one with.

If the current background of `#picture` is X, you have ABC choices, if the background of #picture is Y, you have DEF choices, would be a TLDR explanation maybe.

```
 <div id="adventure">
        <div class="picture">
        </div>

        <div id="choice">
            <button class="button1">Val 1</button>
            <button class="button2">Val 2</button>
            <button class="button3">Val 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>

$('.button1').click(function() {
    $('.picture').css('background-image',
        'url("image1")'
    );
});

  $('.button2').click(function() {
    $('.picture').css('background-image',
        'url("image2")'
    );
});

  $('.button3').click(function() {
    $('.picture').css('background-image',
        'url("image3")'
    );
});
```

I've probably gone about doing this in a bad way but I'm really at a loss on how I would do this. I can only think up of one way of doing it and that is to have a bunch of if statements depending on what background is in the `#picture` div but I don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo relies on the class `.active` which determines which set of buttons (called `.group`) are visible, whilst the other `.group`s remain absent. The `#switch` button will toggle through each group.

You must name your images according to the id of the button it belongs to.

Example:

HTML of Button

```
<button id="image_of_sky.png">D</button>
```

URL to Image

```
http://domain.com/path/to/image_of_sky.png
```

jQuery `img` variable

```
var img = "http://domain.com/path/to/"+btn;
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  var btn = $(this).attr('id');
  var img = "https://placehold.it/330x150?text=" + btn;
  $('.picture').css('background-image',
    'url(' + img + ')'
  );
});

$('#switch').click(function() {
  var act = $('.group.active');
  var next = act.next();
  act.removeClass('active');
  next.addClass('active');
  if (act.attr('id') == "choiceGHI") {
    $('#choiceABC').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
#adventure {
  width: 395px;
}
.picture {
  width: 330px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px outset grey;
}
.group {
  width: 330px;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.button {
  width: 32.5%;
  margin: 0;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
#switch {
  float: right;
  margin: -20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adventure">
  <div class="picture"></div>


  <div id="choiceABC" class="group active">
    <button id="Image1" class="button">A</button>
    <button id="Image2" class="button">B</button>
    <button id="Image3" class="button">C</button>
  </div>
  <div id="choiceDEF" class="group">
    <button id="Image4" class="button">D</button>
    <button id="Image5" class="button">E</button>
    <button id="Image6" class="button">F</button>
  </div>
  <div id="choiceGHI" class="group">
    <button id="Image7" class="button">G</button>
    <button id="Image8" class="button">H</button>
    <button id="Image9" class="button">I</button>
  </div>
  <button id="switch">Switch</button>
</div>
```